# ViewController does not conform to protocol 'GIDSignInDelegate'

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin, gidsignin

I added `GIDSignInDelegate` on my `ViewController` and added function:

```
sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!)
```

but Xcode still complaining about protocol. See [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Te1pX.png)

[Xcode hint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqq0k.png)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation at https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/protocol_g_i_d_sign_in_delegate-p describes two methods. You also need signIn:didDisconnectWithUser:withError:

If you type `func didDisconnect` Xcode should fill it in for you.

Comment: @YgorYuri if you go to the issue navigator and click on the down arrow next to the error, it will show you what is missing. What does it say there?

Comment: Xcode gives me the option to add the func that i already added. Take a look on my answer update

Comment: @YgorYuri That's very bizarre. They certainly look the same. Have you tried applying the fix-it and moving your code into the new function? Just out of curiosity, that makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

It was because I had a class named Error which it was conflicting with google's function.

thanks to evelynklassen in [github](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/267).